# Is there a way to dedupe or group git commits by Jira ticket using git log?

Tags: git, jira, git-log

I am trying to group the git commit messages by Jira ticket using git shortlog so that the file I output the results to only shows 1 (the first) commit per Jira ticket even if there were multiple commits for 1 ticket.

Here is my command so far :

```
git shortlog --no-merges -n --pretty=oneline tagA..tagB >log.txt
```

This results in a format like this :

```
...
Developer (3)
 JIRA-123 blah 1 
 JIRA-123 blah 2 
 JIRA-123 blah 3 
...
```

But I want the format to be this :

```
...
Developer (3)
JIRA-123 blah 1
....
```

Comment: so... remove the space before `JIRA`? pipe it through sed/awk and mangled the string...

Comment: I was hoping there would be some --format or -grep options available with gitl-log, git-revparse, etc.